# Separate configuration file for android tests in multimodule app

Tags: android, dependency-injection, configuration, integration-testing, android-espresso

I have an Android project which has three modules. Each module has it own `config.xml` under `/res/values` folder. This config file has API endpoints and account credentials (addresses).

Now I have to run my integration end-to-end test which is done over espresso from the `:main` module. The question is how to tell the rest modules to use configurations for test environment?

Usually I just define a `config.xml` with test environment under `androidTest/res/values` folder, but in case of multimodule app it would not work as each module has its own config file.
I might try to override DI modules in test and substitute API endpoints. I haven't tried it, but it might work. Although, account credentials from config are used in some other places.

It is also possible to define this variables on the `build.gradle` file, but it would have similar issue like in case of the multiple configs in all modules. I prefer not to put all configuration dependencies into the same `config.xml` or `build.gradle` to let each module to protect each own scope of responsibility.

How would you do solve this scenario?